# using a while loop with multiple conditions

Tags: c

I always get confused with while when I need to use multiple condition. I believe this is correct.

```
1 and 1 = 1
1 and 0 = 0
1 or 1 = 1
1 or 0 = 1
```

Is there something special I need to do with while loops? If statements always seem to behave like I expect with multiple conditions. Is there a good rule of thumb to follow?

Like here. Since I usually try || and it never seems to work I used && first. But Of course I needed an || in this case just because I did the opposite of what I usually do.

```
const char *s = buffer;
parser_comment_level = 0
while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s) || parser_comment_level != 0)
{
}
```

I would like to change the above to. Is that correct or do I need to use an &&? Would it be a good idea to use parenthesis and if so how?

```
const char *s = buffer;
parser_comment_level = 0
while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s) || parser_comment_level != 0 || (unsigned char)*s != '\0')
{
}
```

Comment: you should use only one expression in the loop, for example ` while(ok) ` , and you determine `ok` in several lines.

Comment: Read it as you would in English. `while (A || B) {}` means `while A is true or B is true, do this {}`; `while (A && B) {}` means `while A is true AND B is true, do this {}`.

Comment: "Is it correct?" - only you know that. It's syntactically valid, does that count for anything?

Comment: @royhowie What about `while (!A && B) {}` and `while (!A || B) {}`? Would you need to switch the `&&` to `||` and the `||` to `&`? Would it still be `While !A is true or B is true, do this {}` and `while !A is true AND B is true, do this {}`?

Comment: It depends on what you want. `&&` means "and" and `||` "or." You can use either to construct whatever logical condition you want. `while (!A && B) {}` means `while A is false and B is true, do {}`.

Comment: @rockstar797 Imagine if you were asking that with something different: "What about `A*2 + B` and `A*2 - B`? Would you need to switch the `+` to `-` and the `-` to `++`? Would it still be `A times two plus B`, and `A times two MINUS B`?" - and now you might see why your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @immibis Yes your right. I was thinking about Demorgan's law.

Comment: @royhowie Sorry for being confusing. I was just thinking about Demorgan's law.

Answer (score 0):

So, to dissect `while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s) || parser_comment_level != 0 || (unsigned char)*s != '\0')` we need to understand the interactions between the subexpressions. If any of the subexpressions is true, we must continue looping, so if `(unsigned char)*s != '\0'`, we must continue looping. Therefore it would seem `ispunct((unsigned char)*s)`, which also depends on `*s`, will never actually matter. This is a clue that the expression is wrong.

```
while ((ispunct((unsigned char)*s) || parser_comment_level != 0) && (unsigned char)*s != '\0')
```

Much better. Now, hitting the null terminator will exit the loop, but so will the previous expression.

In a nutshell, use `&&` when either subexpression should exit the loop, and `||` when either subexpression should continue the loop.

Comment: Thank that makes sense `*s` has to be not equal to `null` or you get a seg fault. And there's no point to enter the while loop if `*s` is not punctuation or parser_comment_level not equal to 0.

Comment: Actually, `s` has to be non-null. Here, I'm assuming it does actually point to something. `s` is not something you should check in the `while`, however. It's something which should be checked once before the loop commences.

Comment: @JohnSensebe just to say thank you for this :). `In a nutshell, use && when either subexpression should exit the loop, and || when either subexpression should continue the loop.` It has been so helpful for me since I found it. Whenever I get stuck I search through my internet history for "while" and find this :).